# vim save and restore windows history

Tags: vim

I am working on my plugin which works with a custom buffer holding some info which is not relevant for the problem. And I have a situation like this, on event BufEnter

1. Save current window
2. Save eventignore value
3. Set eventignore = 'all'
4. Remove custom buffer and window
5. Create custom buffer and window
6. Restore eventignore
7. Restore current window

The problem here is that this sequence of actions modifies the history of previously visited windows and I dont' restore it. Some other plugins use this history (for example, result of `winnr('#')`). As a result of they produce "wrong" (unexpected for user) actions. How I can do the operations above without pushing newly created window from my custom buffer to the stack of visited windows?

Comment: I'm not aware of a "window history" feature but you may be looking for `:help :keepalt` and `:help :keepjumps`. Also, see `:help special-buffers`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no "window history", but:

- to preserve the *alternate buffer*, prepend `:keepalt` to any command that would modify it (e.g. `:edit`)
- to preserve the *jump list* (e.g. via `<C-O>`), likewise prepend `:keepjumps`.